# Is developing an OCR considered a research project?

Tags: computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Is developing an optical character recognition system for an alphabet which has no previous ocr considered a reputable conference or journal worthy research project, given the fact that there are so many commercial ocr system? Though, lots of conference proceeding and journal entries shows up when googled, but most of them are old and are about performance of a specific algorithm. There are also research on ocr for cursive alphabets which are hard to segment, like Arabic. The alphabet I am developing ocr for is of Indic origin and cursive as my final year undergraduate thesis. So, I'm wondering if it's a good research project.

Comment: Not unless you have some new ideas that gain insight into the field.  Do you not have a supervisor or advisor to help you out, or is this a personal project?  Do not expect to get it published.  However, as an undergraduate thesis, it might be fine.  Talk to your supervisor.

Comment: This is not a good question for this site; talk to your local expert. (If there is none, you should think twice about doing research on it, at that place.)

Comment: @PålGD For an undergraduate thesis, new insight is not necessary. An aggregation of knowledge leading to a incremental step forward (e.g. a usable tool) can be enough, provided aggregation and/or adaption is non-trivial.

Comment: @Raphael Yeah, that's why I said it might be fine as an undergraduate project.  Rifat starts the question, however, by "reputable conference or journal worthy research project", which I would say that, "Not unless you have some new ideas ...".

Comment: The alphabet(Chakma) has no previous ocr, commercial or research. So, if I apply and determine performance variation of two algorithms, say, k-nearest neighbour and Artificial Neural Networks, is it a good research idea?

Comment: In my university's undergrad theses, supervisors are not actually advisors, we have to go to them with good and convincing research ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rifat, you have to ask your supervisor.  If (s)he accepts, then go for it, otherwise go back to the drawing board.

If this is, as you say, an area for which an OCR does not yet exist, then it sounds perfectly fine for an undergraduate project, but do not expect any reputable conference or journal to publish your results.